# VBA Change Scatter Point to PentagonShape

Tags: vba, excel

I created a Macro which creates ten scatter with color stops. Now i want that the scatter point looks like a pentagon. I created a pentagon and copy paste it to the diagram.

Here you can see how it should look:

[image]

This is what happens when i run the Macro:

[image]

This is my code:

```
Sub Diagramm_OV()

    Dim a As Integer

    a = 1
    Do
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select
        With ActiveChart
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Project Overview'!$E$8"
            .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "={1}"
            .Axes(xlCategory).Select
            .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 100
        End With

        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
        Selection.Delete
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
        Selection.Delete
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
        Selection.Delete
        ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select

        With ActiveChart.PlotArea.Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .TwoColorGradient msoGradientVertical, 1
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            .GradientStops(1).Position = 0
            .GradientStops(2).Position = 1
        End With

        With ActiveSheet
            .Shapes("Diagramm " & a).ScaleHeight 0.3361111111, msoFalse, _
            msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .Shapes("Diagramm " & a).IncrementLeft 117.6
            .Shapes("Diagramm " & a).IncrementTop -107.4
            .ChartObjects("Diagramm " & a).Activate
            .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapePentagon, 150, 244.8, 24.6, 7.8).Select
        End With

        ' Create Pentagon and copy it
        Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementRotation 90
        Selection.Copy

        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm " & a).Activate

        ' Paste Pentagon to Scatter
        With ActiveChart
            .FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
            .Paste
        End With

        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm " & a).ScaleHeight 0.7685950413, msoFalse, _
            msoScaleFromTopLeft
        a = a + 2
    Loop Until a = 10
End Sub
```

I hope someone can help me, that the pentagon will be the scatter.